# In Backbone how to get click event on an anchor tag within a list item

Tags: javascript, jquery, backbone.js, backbone-views, jquery-click-event

In a backbone view within the render function I have an anchor tag with a list item inside a unordered list. in short

```
var DemoView = Backbone.View.extend({
  el: '#body',
  
  render: function() {
    this.$('sidebar-nav > ul').append($('<li class="divider"></li>'));
    this.$('.sidebar-nav > ul')
      .append($('<li><a href="' + _.path(Overture.contextPath, '/calendars/', 
    this.controller.model.id,'/preview') + '" class="internal-link">Link 1</a></li>'));
    this.$('.sidebar-nav > ul')
        .append($('<li><a href="#" class="internal-link">Link 2</a></li>'));
  } 
});
```

I want to open an alert box on the click on **Link 2** without navigating to some other page.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can setup the View's `events`:

```js
var DemoView = Backbone.View.extend({
  el: '#body',
  events: {
    'click .alert-link': onAlertLinkClick
  },
  onAlertLinkClick: function() {
     // put your alert code here
  },
  render: function() {
    this.$('sidebar-nav > ul').append($('<li class="divider"></li>'));
    this.$('.sidebar-nav > ul')
      .append($('<li><a href="' + _.path(Overture.contextPath, '/calendars/', 
    this.controller.model.id,'/preview') + '" class="internal-link">Link 1</a></li>'));
    this.$('.sidebar-nav > ul')
        .append($('<li><a href="#" class="internal-link alert-link">Link 2</a></li>'));
  } 
});
```

You have to add the `alert-link` to the second anchor to select it of course.

[See docs](https://backbonejs.org/#View-events) for more info.